# Why when you create a Postman Documentation the JSON body is displayed incorrectly?

Tags: postman

Here is the link of the AUTO-GENERATED POSTMAN DOCUMENTATION https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/4667518/T1LLFUEx?version=latest

I'm trying to create documentation easy to understand and I decided to use postman for this task. But it looks like the body it's being interpreted as text and not as a Javascript Object. Is there a way to fix this, or do you recommend me using another tool?

This is how it looks in Postman:

[image: Postman RAW JSON Body for HTTP Post Request]

And this is how it looks in the postman auto-generated documentation example when it is "Simulating" or "Assuming" that you are using Javascript.

[image]

Comment: What's the example of that request look like, that's what's driving that view in the documentation

Comment: That's the "Register User Post Request" example

Comment: Yes, what does that look like and are the correct Headers set on it?

Comment: Yes, the headers are set as JSON in the content type.